# Is there any other way to use pyinstaller?

Tags: cmd, pyinstaller

I made an python script that use few phonenumbers dependencies and pySimpleGUI. It's an basic GUI program that gives me info about number i type in. I'm running Windows 10. I watched few tutorials and it said that i need to install pyinstaller and then type

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

which i did but it gives me an error:

pyinstaller : The term 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pyinstaller
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I tried with path to the pyinstaller but it's same. The tutorials were old so i watched the new ones, but they say the same thing.